# select python code from info view

Tags: python, interface

I'm trying to copy python text from the info view, but I can't select any text. I tried 2.6.4 and 2.7.6. Am I doing something wrong?

I'm using Blender on OS X 10.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the *UserPreferences->Input->Info*

[image]

The 'Select Mouse' on window is a right-click. This will highlight a line, and the same action to remove the highlight. Whatever you use on the Mac to select geometry, should be the same key that will work in the info-window to select lines.

Copy Reports: will copy highlighted reports.

**short-comings:** (November 2015)
It isn't currently possible to select part of a line, it's the whole line or nothing.

Comment: Thanks! I changed Mouse from Select Mouse to Left Mouse and now I can select line by line.

Comment: Oh OK. interesting! I would have expected the equivalent of geometry selection to work on the info panel.